# SOAP Equivelant of RESTs /chatter/users/me/conversations?

Tags: soql, rest-api, chatter, soap-api

Title pretty much says it, I know that in REST we query private conversations using the above endpoint `/chatter/users/{ID}/conversations`, but I'm not sure where to look for the same thing in SOAP. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ChatterConversation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_chatterconversation.htm) and [ChatterMessage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_chattermessage.htm) seem like the API objects you want.

Note that you will need the "Manage Chatter Messages" permission to see these via the API.

This is a bit of a guess, but will hopefully point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT Id,ConversationId,Body,SentDate FROM ChatterMessage where SenderId = '005100000000000'
```

Comment: How would I activate this via an application?

Comment: @ehime Are you referring to the permission or how to send the SOQL query via the Partner API?

Comment: I am, since we are working with direct or free signups via chatter.com we are being severly limited on how we can interact with these users, as some (most) do not have an administrative user in place to alter permissions.

Comment: @ehime I don't know how to alter administrative permissions for a user that directly signed up to chatter.com. Seems like a good candidate for a separate question.